# Searching contents on HTTP authenticated search

Tags: search, google-search

I really don't know whether this is a right place to ask this question. I tried post this question in quora, but when i click "Add Question" button on the last step, it does not work wand infact i'm seeing error 500 in firebug.

Well. My question is here. Is there any way to search the content of HTTP authenticated site, if the authentication details are provided preferably using Google?

Comment: "the content of HTTP"? What do you mean exactly in that

Comment: @GuyL Just to search the contents of the site like what Google is doing in regular sites.